# FFmpeg stream video to rtmp from frames OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

In the context of indistural project, i developed a real time application to detect person with AI algorithms. In local i get and display videos with OPENCV operating with frames.

**The objective is to realise a stream video from frames of Opencv to rtmp server**

FFmpeg seems a good perspective. However, often the stream strats from .mp4 or several .jpg to publish stream video on rtmp server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly ffmpeg is functional for pushing stream to rtmp server.
you can try create a subprocess for ffmpeg cammand, and pass your frames through PIPE.

Here is an simple example code you can try

```py
import subprocess
import cv2
rtmp_url = "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/stream/pupils_trace"

# In my mac webcamera is 0, also you can set a video file name instead, for example "/home/user/demo.mp4"
path = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

# gather video info to ffmpeg
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# command and params for ffmpeg
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
           '-s', "{}x{}".format(width, height),
           '-r', str(fps),
           '-i', '-',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-preset', 'ultrafast',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rtmp_url]

# using subprocess and pipe to fetch frame data
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)


while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("frame read failed")
        break

    # YOUR CODE FOR PROCESSING FRAME HERE

    # write to pipe
    p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response !
by passing my frames through PIPE I manage to broadcast my video stream in real time.
I also found rigorous documentation in line with AI projects :  https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python/blob/master/examples/README.md#tensorflow-streaming

Comment: i'm really new to pyhton, in my case, i'll stream a video instead of webcam. reading file part is okay. But i couldn't manage network side, i've got;
`[rtmp @ 000002649f951c40] Cannot open connection tcp://127.0.0.1:1935` error

I'm working on windows, what should i do, could you have an answer @admingyu please

Comment: I keep getting a broken pipe error on this code

    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 640x480, 221184 kb/s, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
rtmp://f7a22cf.channel.media.azure.net:1935/live/c9c612df8: I/O error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\singh\source\try.py", line 41, in <module>
    p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())