# Python opencv subprocess write return broken pipe

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, subprocess, video-streaming

I want to read an rtsp video source, add overlay text and push it to the RTMP endpoint.I am using Videocapture to read the video source and python subprocess to write the frames back to RTMP endpoint. I referred this [FFmpeg stream video to rtmp from frames OpenCV python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769828/ffmpeg-stream-video-to-rtmp-from-frames-opencv-python)

```
import sys
import subprocess

import cv2
import ffmpeg
rtmp_url = "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test"

path = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://10.0.1.7/media.sdp")

# gather video info to ffmpeg
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))



command = ['ffmpeg', '-i', '-', "-c", "copy", '-f', 'flv', rtmp_url]
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
while cap.isOpened():

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.putText(frame, 'TEXT ON VIDEO', (50, 50), font, 1, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
    cv2.imshow('video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    if not ret:
        print("frame read failed")
        break

    try:
        p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)


cap.release()
p.stdin.close()
p.stderr.close()
p.wait()
```

The python script returns "[Errno 32] Broken pipe". Running the ffmpeg command in the terminal works fine.

> ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.1.7/media.sdp -c copy -f flv
> rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test

The above command works fine, and I can push the input stream to RTMP endpoint. But I can't write processed frame to subprocess which has ffmpeg running.

Please let me know, if I miss anything.

Comment: why do you use `universal_newlines=True` when you are moving binary data? you move binary data without headers to the subprocess. why do you not specify the data format to ffmpeg? it won't know what to expect or how to interpret it.

Comment: Infact I removed and tested still same error.

Comment: you gave a link to a solution. you should follow it more precisely. you don't, which causes your issue.

Comment: Only difference between the link and my code is codec. I can't use those codec for my camera, so I used COPY codec

Comment: I'm sorry, what? which codecs do you mean exactly? and why "can't" you? consider the possibility that you don't understand the code in the linked solution.

Comment: It works with -c libx264. When I use -c copy, it is not working. Using libx264 codec fails to play my stream Webrtc player

Comment: it shouldn't have worked with anything other than `-f rawvideo`. you should have stuck with `-f rawvideo` as demonstrated in the answer you linked. why did you change that? using anything other than `-f rawvideo` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `"-c", "copy"` when writing raw frames to stdin PIPE.

The `frame` returned by `ret, frame = cap.read()` is a `uint8` NumPy array in BGR color format (`cap.read()` decodes the video and converts the color format).
In `FFmpeg` terminology, the `frame` format is "`rawvideo`".

- The `command` should tell FFmpeg to expect raw video as input, with specific size and pixel format:
  `command = ['ffmpeg', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-s', f'{width}x{height}', '-pixel_format', 'bgr24', ...`
- Because the input is raw video, we have to re-encode it.
  We may specify the encoded pixel format and video codec:
  `'-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-c:v', 'libx264' ...`.

Remarks:

- Decoding and re-encoding the video looses some quality (but there is no choice).
- The suggested solution looses the audio (there are solutions that preserves the audio, but OpenCV lack audio support).
- The posted solution reuses some code from the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545688/stream-images-from-python-opencv-with-ffmpeg).
  Few FFmpeg arguments are taken with no explanation (like `'-bufsize', '64M'`).

---

Executing a listener application:

- The RTMP streaming, is not going to work, without a "listener" that receives the video.
  The listener should be started before starting the RTMP streaming (due to TCP usage).
- We may use FFplay sub-process as "listener" application:

  ```
   ffplay_process = sp.Popen(['ffplay', '-listen', '1', '-i', rtmp_url])
  ```

---

Streaming synthetic video frames:

Start with a simpler code sample, that streams synthetic frames (without capturing RTSP video).

The following "self contained" code sample writes yellow text on gray background, and passes the frames to FFmpeg for RTMP streaming:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import subprocess as sp 

width = 320
height = 240

fps = 5

rtmp_url = "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test"

# Start the TCP server first, before the sending client.
ffplay_process = sp.Popen(['ffplay', '-listen', '1', '-i', rtmp_url])  # Use FFplay sub-process for receiving the RTMP video.


command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-re',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',  # Apply raw video as input
           '-s', f'{width}x{height}',
           '-pixel_format', 'bgr24',
           '-r', f'{fps}',
           '-i', '-',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-bufsize', '64M',
           '-maxrate', '4M',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rtmp_url]

process = sp.Popen(command, stdin=sp.PIPE)  # Execute FFmpeg sub-process for RTSP streaming

frame_counter = 0;

while True:
    # Build sythetic frame in BGR color format (3D NumPy array).
    frame = np.full((height, width, 3), 60, np.uint8)
    cv2.putText(frame, 'TEXT ON VIDEO ' + str(frame_counter), (20, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)  # Put a frame counter for showing progress.

    process.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())  # Write raw frame to stdin pipe.

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)  # Show frame for testing

    key = cv2.waitKey(int(round(1000/fps)))  # We need to call cv2.waitKey after cv2.imshow

    if key == ord('q'):  # Press 'q' for exit
        break

    frame_counter += 1

process.stdin.close()  # Close stdin pipe
process.wait()  # Wait for FFmpeg sub-process to finish
ffplay_process.kill()  # Forcefully close FFplay sub-process
cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # Close OpenCV window
```

---

Output sample:
[image]

---

Capturing video frames from RTSP stream.
The following code sample captures video frames from a [public RTSP stream](https://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html), writes text, and passes the frames to FFmpeg for RTMP streaming:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import subprocess as sp 

# Use public RTSP Streaming for testing.
rtsp_stream = "rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov"

rtmp_url = "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_stream)

# gather video info to ffmpeg
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))


# Start the TCP server first, before the sending client.
ffplay_process = sp.Popen(['ffplay', '-listen', '1', '-i', rtmp_url])  # Use FFplay sub-process for receiving the RTMP video.


command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-re',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',  # Apply raw video as input
           '-s', f'{width}x{height}',
           '-pixel_format', 'bgr24',
           '-r', f'{fps}',
           '-i', '-',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-bufsize', '64M',
           '-maxrate', '4M',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rtmp_url]

process = sp.Popen(command, stdin=sp.PIPE)  # Execute FFmpeg sub-process for RTSP streaming

frame_counter = 0;

while cap.isOpened():
    # Read frame from RTSP stream.
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print("frame read failed")
        break

    cv2.putText(frame, 'TEXT ON VIDEO', (0, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
    cv2.putText(frame, str(frame_counter), (100, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)

    process.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())  # Write raw frame to stdin pipe.

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)  # Show frame for testing

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)  # We need to call cv2.waitKey after cv2.imshow

    if key == ord('q'):  # Press 'q' for exit
        break

    frame_counter += 1

cap.release()
process.stdin.close()  # Close stdin pipe
process.wait()  # Wait for FFmpeg sub-process to finish
ffplay_process.kill()  # Forcefully close FFplay sub-process
cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # Close OpenCV window
```

---

Output sample:
[image]